# HTML, CSS, haml - problems with relative links on a layout for a padrino/sinatra/rails style static website generator

Tags: html, middleman, static-site, relative-url

I am using a static site generator to make a site that sits on a shared network folder at my job. It's a simple tutorial site for my co-workers—it's not hosted, there's no server, and it's completely static. I am using [the Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/), which is a great app. I just need it to publish a website I can use from a folder like this.

The problem is that my `index.html` and other HTML files are in different folders. The web structure is like this:

```
-index.html
 +guides/
  -guide1.html
  -guide2.html
 +stylesheets/
 +images/
```

...you get the idea. My navigation is all in my `layout.haml`, however, every time I navigate outside of my root `index.html`, the `nab` links get all messed up. If I use (../) or (./) they look to folders that don't even exist. Here is a piece of my current `layout.haml` nav (you can see I tried a couple of things):

```
%nav
    %ul
        %li.div= link_to 'Home', "index.html"
        %li
            %a{:href => ("/guides/getting-started.html")} Getting Started
        %li= link_to 'Tool Tip 1', "guides/tooltip1.html"
        %li= link_to 'Tool Tip 2', "guides/tooltip2.html"
        %li= link_to 'Tool Tip 3', "guides/tooltip3.html"
```

It was suggested that I put a 'helpers do' in my config.rb. It should look something like this:

```
helpers do
  def relative_link_to(text, url)
    # Get current path
    # Get path of url
    # Get relative relation between paths
    # Pass new data to the original link_to helper
    link_to(text, relative_url)
  end
end
```

That's the point where I got lost, the 'helpers do' part. Can someone point me in the right direction or just help me out?

Answer (score 1):

What about a `link_to 'Tool Tip 1', "/guides/tooltip1.html"`  - notice the leading slash.